# fatest way to mix two lists in python

Tags: python, list

Let's have 2 lists

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g...]
```

result:

```
list = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c, d, e, f, g...]
```

Cannot use `zip()` because it shorten result to the smallest `list`. I need also a `list` at the output not an `iterable`.

Comment: Fastest, most elegant, or most pythonic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
>>> [i for i in itertools.chain(*itertools.izip_longest(l1,l2)) if i is not None]
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

To allow `None` values to be included in the lists you can use the following modification:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, izip_longest
>>> l1 = [1, None, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
>>> sentinel = object()
>>> [i
     for i in chain(*izip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=sentinel))
     if i is not sentinel]
[1, 'a', None, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: No need for that double parenthesis there. `itertools.chain((...))` can simply be `itertools.chain(...)`. Oh and you might want to encapsulate the whole thing in `list(...)`.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility...

```
[y for x in izip_longest(l1, l2) for y in x if y is not None]
```

(after importing izip_longest from itertools, of course)

Comment: This is preferred even if not the most descriptive. :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to use the round robin recipie given in [the `itertools` docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Which can be used like so:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
>>> list(roundrobin(l1, l2))
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Note that 2.x requires a slightly different version of `roundrobin`, provided in [the 2.x docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes).

This also avoids the problem the `zip_longest()` method has in that the lists can contain `None` without it being stripped out.

Comment: I don't know if I would call that the simplest, considering the whole new function you have to define to make it work.

Comment: @asmeurer As it's a given recipe, it's not exactly a hardship to include it. It also has the benefit I mention at the bottom - if the list contains ``None`` the ``zip_longest()`` methods don't work as intended. Front a usage point of view, the function is clear and simple.

Comment: @Lattyware I added a simple fix for the `None` issue to the `izip_longest` solution. The only advantage I can see with this method now is the speed advantage of not having to potentially iterate through and discard a large number of sentinels.

Comment: @jamylak I think this solution is clearer and more readable, which is valuable in itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
minLen = len(l1) if len(l1) < len(l2) else len(l2)
for i in range(0, minLen):
  list[2*i] = l1[i]
  list[2*i+1] = l2[i]
list[i*2+2:] = l1[i+1:] if len(l1) > len(l2) else l2[i+1:]
```

this is not a short way but it removes unnecessary dependencies.

update:
here is another way that was suggested by @jsvk

```
mixed = []
for i in range( len(min(l1, l2)) ):
  mixed.append(l1[i])
  mixed.append(l2[i])
list += max(l1, l2)[i+1:]
```

Comment: What "unnecessary dependencies" are you referring to? The only other dependency expressed by any other solution here thus far is `itertools`, which is part of the python standard library.

Comment: yes but it still has to be loaded by the interpreter.
I'm not saying that the other solutions are not good, they are probably better for most purposes, but I just posted another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the output in a single list, instead of a list of tuples, try this.

```
Out=[]
[(Out.extend(i) for i in (itertools.izip_longest(l1,l2))]
Out=filter(None, Out)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim that this is the best way to do it, but I just wanted to point out that it is possible to use zip:

```
b = zip(l1, l2)
a = []
[a.extend(i) for i in b]
a.extend(max([l1, l2], key=len)[len(b):])

>>> a
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: Except it won't work in Python 3 as written, because `len(zip)` is not defined there.

Comment: Using a list comprehension for side effects is also a bad idea. Use ``itertools.chain()`` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = list("abcdefg")
>>> [x for e in zip(a, b) for x in e] + b[len(a):]
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: This presumes ``b`` is longer than ``a`` - although that can be fixed with some more code.